# how to implement custom number picker android

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to implement number picker like this

[image]

I want to replace digits with images and selectionDivider with image.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker3"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/numberPicker2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have a number picker in dialogfragment

Answer (score 1):

please check this [android-wheel](https://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) library i think this is what you are looking for

and give me some feddback

Hope That Helps .